# Addition of a list and an integer

Tags: python, list, function

The input of this code is a list(x), containing numbers which  represent an integer: i.e (`[1,2,3]` = 123)
the second number is an integer (y).
The purpose of the code is to produce a new(or just change the existing list) to be the sum of x+y by using the function which I wrote below.
i.e;

```
x = [1,2,3]
y = 11
#output is [1,3,4]
```

I'd like to preface that this is an exercise, so I would appreciate any feedback but would like to ask of you guys to refrain from "here is how you should write it, {insert code}".

p.s I'm avoiding importing anything and try to code just with the basic python functions.

ok so let me first explain why I wrote what I wrote:

the first part:

```
b = [int(d) for d in str(y)]
    if len(x) <= len(b):
        for j in range(len(b)-len(x)+1):
            x.insert(j,0)
    max1 = int(max(len(x),len(b)))
```

I took the integer "y" and turned him into a list because I want to try and do this whole thing using lists mainly because I want to use them more (I'm kind of bad when it comes to lists),
the next part is a byproduct of the for loop I wrote as it wouldn't work if the first integer is smaller then the second, so by adding zeros to the start of the list I can just delete them if I don't need em'

```
for i in range(1,max1+1):
        if i <= len(b):
            if x[-i] + b[-i] > 10:
                x[-i] = (x[-i]+b[-i])%10
                x[-i-1] = (x[-i-1] + 1)
            elif (x[-i]+b[-i]) < 10:
                x[-i] = x[-i] + b[-i]
            elif (x[-i]+b[-i]) == 10:
                x[-i] = 0
                x[-i-1] = x[-i-1] + 1
         else:
             break
```

this part is just addition like you do in grade school, "vertical addition" if you will,(my first language isn't English so I honestly can't find a better term for it) the thing is if, lets say, I need to add 999 + 1 then it's kind of enjoying doing it with "i" so I decided to make a separate loop for it:

```
x.insert(0,0)
    for k in range(1,len(x)):
        if x[-k] == 10:
            x[-k] = 0
            x[-k-1] = x[-k-1] + 1
        if x[0] >= 10:
            x[1] = x[1]%10 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[0] == 0:
            del x[0]
        else:
            break
    return x
```

so this is the part which I hate the most, the second loop. I couldn't figure out how to integrate it into the original loop....
so first I insert a zero for the worst case of having to add something like  999 + 1 by that I mean having to make the list larger (in my example the x list has 3 items but the addition will yield a 4 item list) and if by someway 'x[0]' is 0 I'm just deleting, that's it basically.

```
    def addition(x,y):
    b = [int(d) for d in str(y)]
    if len(x) <= len(b):
        for j in range(len(b)-len(x)+1):
            x.insert(j,0)
    max1 = int(max(len(x),len(b)))
    for i in range(1,max1+1):
        if i <= len(b):
            if x[-i] + b[-i] > 10:
                x[-i] = (x[-i]+b[-i])%10
                x[-i-1] = (x[-i-1] + 1)
            elif (x[-i]+b[-i]) < 10:
                x[-i] = x[-i] + b[-i]
            elif (x[-i]+b[-i]) == 10:
                x[-i] = 0
                x[-i-1] = x[-i-1] + 1
        else:
            break
    x.insert(0,0)
    for k in range(1,len(x)):
        if x[-k] == 10:
            x[-k] = 0
            x[-k-1] = x[-k-1] + 1
        if x[0] >= 10:
            x[1] = x[1]%10 
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[0] == 0:
            del x[0]
        else:
            break
    return x

x = [int(s) for s in input().split(",")]
y = int(input())        
print(addition(x,y))
```

I've added the full code above.
the code works but it's so messy and that lest loop just kills me it adds additional run time and if you could suggest a better way of implementing or giving any sort of criticism of what I can try to improve or if you see things that in your opinion are just plain bad please share your opinions I would like to improve this as much as I can

p.s sorry for meh english

Comment: Is the code working? Are you asking for code review? If so, look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: All of the answers posted are 'better' ways to accomplish interpreting a list of digits as an integer and adding it to another integer, then converting back to a list of digits.

However, if you're trying to understand how to code digit-wise addition like you would do on paper, this is about as good as you'll get. It's not trivial, which is why stuff like this is implemented directly in microarchitecture instruction sets and not in code.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one liner functional approach to achieve it using `map`:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = 11
    
>>> list(map(int, str(int(''.join(map(str, x))) + y)))
[1, 3, 4]

# OR, List Comprehension at final step to prevent additional type-casting 
# [int(num) for num in str(int(''.join(map(str, x))) + y)]
```

Here's a detailed version of above solution explaining each step:

```
num_str_list = map(str, x)              #  ['1', '2', '3']
num_str = ''.join(num_str_list)         #  '123'
num = int(num_str) + y                  #  134
new_num_str = str(num)                  #  '134'
new_list = list(map(int, new_num_str))  #  [1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: To keep the functional style: `list(map(int, str(int(''.join(map(str, x))) + y)))`

Comment: @Matthias Thanks. updated the answer. I used the version with map as final step earlier, but later updated it to prevent additional type-casting at start. But included both now

Comment: It's a nice task to play around. There are a lot of different approaches like building the sum with `sum(v * 10 ** exp for exp, v in enumerate(x[::-1]))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(x): 
    # Converting integer list to string list 
    s = [str(i) for i in x] 
              
    # Join list items using join() 
    res = int("".join(s)) 
              
    return(res) 
          
x = [1, 2, 3] 
y = 11
num = convert(x) + y  # at first convert the list to an integer and then add another integer
result = [int(i) for i in str(num)] # create list from the integer
    
print(result) #print the list after the addition
```

The output would be: [1, 3, 4]
I have added comments in the code for understanding each line

Comment: btw don’t use ‘list’ as a variable name.

Comment: I changed it. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @MdSajid seems like you are still using it in `[str(i) for i in list] `

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's what happens when you try to edit manually!

Answer (score 1):

You should do the addition as integers:

```py
def addition(x,y):
    xint = int(‘’.join([str(d) for d in x]))
    s = xint + y
    return [int(d) for d in str(s)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The only "fancy" things I'm doing here are list-comprehensions, `sum`, and `zip`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = 11

# In this case, multipliers will be: [100, 10, 1]
multipliers = [10**i for i in range(len(x)-1, -1, -1)]

# 1 * 100 = 100
# 2 * 10 = 20
# 3 * 1 = 3
# 100 + 20 + 3 + y = 134
new_sum = sum([a*b for a, b in zip(x, multipliers)], y)

# Now, turn the integer 134 into the list [1, 3, 4]
new_x = []

for multiplier in multipliers:
    new_x.append(new_sum // multiplier)
    new_sum %= multiplier

print(new_x)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 4]
>>>
```